# shared object file open error with "sudo command" but NOT with "sudo bash" then same command?

Tags: linux, sudo, libraries

I'm having a hard time getting my brain wrapped around how LD_LIBRARY_PATH is handled differently for the following three cases:

- run as a regular user
- run via "*sudo command*"
- run via "*sudo bash*" followed in the root shell by "*command*"

My particular problem is that a binary I'm trying to run (called dc_full) requires sudo access, but throws the following error when run as "sudo command":

```
ljw@test$ sudo ./dc_full 
./dc_full: error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-0.9.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

ljw@test$ sudo bash
root@ljw-vm1:~/test# ./dc_full
.
...<works fine here!> 
.
```

I have the following line in both /etc/bash.bashrc and in ~/.bashrc for user ljw.

```
root@ljw-vm1:~# grep LD_LIBRARY ~/.bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib

root@ljw-vm1:~# grep LD_LIBRARY /etc/bash.bashrc 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

I would expect that this covers both the sudo and sudo-bash cases, one covers the user shell and one covers the "root" shell.  But clearly this is not happening.

I found references to ldd, which gives me a big hint that it's not working, but not quite WHY...

```
root@ljw-vm1:~/dc_full# ldd ./dc_full | grep thrift
    libthrift-0.9.1.so => /usr/local/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.so (0x00007eff19e7c000)

ljw@ljw-vm1:~/dc_full$ ldd ./dc_full | grep thrift
    libthrift-0.9.1.so => /usr/local/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.so (0x00007f8340cc5000)

ljw@ljw-vm1:~/dc_full$ sudo ldd ./dc_full | grep thrift
[sudo] password for ljw:
    libthrift-0.9.1.so => not found
```

How is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in each of these three cases?

Comment: [Relevant SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261954/436063)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allowing LD_LIBRARY_PATH for suid binaries like sudo is a security problem, thus LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets stripped out of the environment. sudo by default doesn't passthrough LD_LIBRARY_PATH to its children either for the same security concerns: carefully crafted libraries would allow you to bypass the sudo argument restrictions to execute whatever you want.

If you need a variable set like this either use `sudo -E`, or pass the env variables on the command line like so: `sudo -- LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib dc_full`. sudo will have to be configured to allow you to pass environment variables, which usually does not need manual configuration.

Comment: For more information, you should read the ["Command environment" section of the sudoers(5) manpage](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html#x436f6d6d616e6420656e7669726f6e6d656e74). It outlines the environment preservation rules in place.

Answer (score 3):

Add /usr/local/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig, then you'll have this path added as a default path for libraries.